# How to show the previous User Control from current User Control?

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I am using windows forms.

[image: screenshot]

As shown in screenshot, I have form1 with 4 buttons and 4 user controls.

click `show UserControl1` and `UserControl1` shows up.

click `show UserControl2` and `UserControl2` shows up.

click `show UserControl3` and `UserControl3` shows up.

click  `show UserControl4` and `UserControl4` shows up.

what I want to do is: when I click `Show Previous UC` (on User Control4) , the previous User Control shows up.

for example:

click  `show UserControl2` and `UserControl2` shows up. 
click  `show UserControl4` and `UserControl4` shows up.

and now I want when I click `Show Previous UC`, `UserControl2` shows up (the previous user control).

How Can I show the previous User Control ( the last one which was shown before the current one)?
Please help me, Thank you.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
  {

    UserControl1 UC1 = new UserControl1();
    UserControl2 UC2 = new UserControl2();
    UserControl3 UC3 = new UserControl3();
    UserControl4 UC4 = new UserControl4();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Controls.Add(UC1);
        Controls.Add(UC2);
        Controls.Add(UC3);
        Controls.Add(UC4);
    }


    private void ShowUserControl1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UC1.Visible = true;

        UC2.Visible = false;
        UC3.Visible = false;
        UC4.Visible = false;
    }

    private void ShowUserControl2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UC2.Visible = true;

        UC1.Visible = false;
        UC3.Visible = false;
        UC4.Visible = false;
    }

    private void ShowUserControl3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UC3.Visible = true;

        UC1.Visible = false;
        UC2.Visible = false;
        UC4.Visible = false;
    }

    private void ShowUserControl4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UC4.Visible = true;

        UC3.Visible = false;
        UC2.Visible = false;
        UC1.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using an array. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of which user control was the previous in the page (and possible also the current, unless you want to iterate the UCs to find out). Use fields for this in the page.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    UserControl[] userControls = new []{ 
        new UserControl1(), 
        new UserControl2(),
        new UserControl3(),
        new UserControl4()
    };
    UserControl previous;
    UserControl current;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        foreach(var uc in UserControls)
        {
            uc.Click += ShowPrevControl_Click;
            Controls.Add(uc);
        }
    }
```

In the event (you only need one)

```
private void ShowUserControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(UserControl uc in UserControls)
    {
        if(uc.Name == (string)((Control)sender).Tag)
        {
            previous = current;
            uc.Visible = true;
            current = uc;
        }
        else
        { 
            uc.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}

private void ShowPrevControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (previous != null) 
    {
        foreach(var uc in UserControls)
        {
            uc.Visible = false;
        }
        var temp = current;
        previous.Visible = true; 
        current = previous;
        previous = temp; 
    }
}
```

Set the Tag property for each button to hold the name of the UserControl it should control (UserControl1, UserControl2, UserControl3 or UserControl4).

Let all the buttons click events be handled by `ShowUserControl_Click`.

Create a new public event in your user controls (if all should handle clicks), that that page can handle using your `ShowPrevControl_Click`method:

```
public UserControlx : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler Click;

    public UserControlx()
    {
        Button.Click += Button_Click;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Click != null)
            Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to add a member variable to your class.

So your class would look like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    UserControl prevControl;
    // Etc...
```

So when you click the button for, say, UC2, you can set prevControl to UC2.

```
private void ShowUserControl2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UC2.Visible = true;
    prevControl = UC2;

    UC1.Visible = false;
    UC3.Visible = false;
    UC4.Visible = false;
}
```

And on an event handler for the "Show previous control" button:

```
private void ShowPrevControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (prevControl != null) prevControl.Visible = true;
}
```

`UserControl` is a reference in C#, which makes this possible.

Comment: Tobe O @ . Thank you for you answer but the code did not work. I add the " if (prevControl != null) prevControl.Visible = true;"  into "ShowPrevControl_Click" i gives error (the name "prevControl" does not exist in current context) . prevControl is declared in Form1 so how can I access it form user control4?  I tried:  (Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
            frm1.prevControl.Visible = true;) but it gives error :  ( Object reference not set to an instance of an object ) any idea?  thank you

Comment: @naouf: Don't forget to assign the value of prevControl when you click on any of the other buttons. If you look at my modified `ShowUserControl2_Click`, you'll notice I added `prevControl = UC2;`.

Comment: @  Tobe O . I did exactly what you wrote but I still get this error " the name "prevControl" does not exist in current context"  and the complier points to : "ShowPrevControl_Click" ---> "prevControl" is underlined with red color. is sounds that user Control4 can not access  "prevControl" ehich declared on Form1. Can you help please. Thank you

Comment: PHeiberg's answer is more complete, so check out what he did. The same concept prevails, though. A reference to the previous control should be a member variable in your class. And when you switch controls, make sure to update the value of prevControl. Secondly, make sure that the "show previous" button is hooked up to the event handler we created. :)